# Unable to Parse XML using LINQ in ASP.Net & C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Horizon-Export>
  <BatchNo.>1</BatchNo.>
  <SpecimenID>CL1</SpecimenID>
  <OperatorName>Anuj</OperatorName>
  <SpecimenAge>1.00</SpecimenAge>
  <Grade>M12</Grade>
  <DateofCasting>01/09/2012</DateofCasting>
  <SpecimenShape>Cube</SpecimenShape>
  <SpecimenSize>150.00</SpecimenSize>
  <Area>22,500</Area>
  <Weight>10.0</Weight>
  <Density>1.00</Density>
  <TestDate>17/09/2012</TestDate>
  <TestTime>9:41:08 AM</TestTime>
  <BatchDate>17/09/2012</BatchDate>
  <UltimateForce>
  </UltimateForce>
  <UltimateStress>
  </UltimateStress>
  <Remarks>Pass</Remarks>
  <BatchNo.>1</BatchNo.>
  <SpecimenID>CL1</SpecimenID>
  <OperatorName>Anuj</OperatorName>
  <SpecimenAge>1.00</SpecimenAge>
  <Grade>M12</Grade>
  <DateofCasting>01/09/2012</DateofCasting>
  <SpecimenShape>Cube</SpecimenShape>
  <SpecimenSize>150.00</SpecimenSize>
  <Area>22,500</Area>
  <Weight>10.0</Weight>
  <Density>1.00</Density>
  <TestDate>17/09/2012</TestDate>
  <TestTime>9:47:10 AM</TestTime>
  <BatchDate>17/09/2012</BatchDate>
  <UltimateForce>25.3</UltimateForce>
  <UltimateStress>1.12</UltimateStress>
  <Remarks>Pass</Remarks>
  <BatchNo.>1</BatchNo.>
  <SpecimenID>CL1</SpecimenID>
  <OperatorName>Anuj</OperatorName>
  <SpecimenAge>1.00</SpecimenAge>
  <Grade>M12</Grade>
  <DateofCasting>01/09/2012</DateofCasting>
  <SpecimenShape>Cube</SpecimenShape>
  <SpecimenSize>150.00</SpecimenSize>
  <Area>22,500</Area>
  <Weight>10.0</Weight>
  <Density>1.00</Density>
  <TestDate>17/09/2012</TestDate>
  <TestTime>9:48:57 AM</TestTime>
  <BatchDate>17/09/2012</BatchDate>
  <UltimateForce>8.3</UltimateForce>
  <UltimateStress>0.37</UltimateStress>
  <Remarks>Pass</Remarks>
  <BatchNo.>1</BatchNo.>
  <SpecimenID>CL1</SpecimenID>
  <OperatorName>Anuj</OperatorName>
  <SpecimenAge>1.00</SpecimenAge>
  <Grade>M12</Grade>
  <DateofCasting>01/09/2012</DateofCasting>
  <SpecimenShape>Cube</SpecimenShape>
  <SpecimenSize>150.00</SpecimenSize>
  <Area>22,500</Area>
  <Weight>10.0</Weight>
  <Density>1.00</Density>
  <TestDate>17/09/2012</TestDate>
  <TestTime>9:49:20 AM</TestTime>
  <BatchDate>17/09/2012</BatchDate>
  <UltimateForce>10.9</UltimateForce>
  <UltimateStress>0.49</UltimateStress>
  <Remarks>Pass</Remarks>
  <BatchNo.>1</BatchNo.>
  <SpecimenID>CL1</SpecimenID>
  <OperatorName>Anuj</OperatorName>
  <SpecimenAge>1.00</SpecimenAge>
  <Grade>M12</Grade>
  <DateofCasting>01/09/2012</DateofCasting>
  <SpecimenShape>Cube</SpecimenShape>
  <SpecimenSize>150.00</SpecimenSize>
  <Area>22,500</Area>
  <Weight>10.0</Weight>
  <Density>1.00</Density>
  <TestDate>17/09/2012</TestDate>
  <TestTime>9:49:42 AM</TestTime>
  <BatchDate>17/09/2012</BatchDate>
  <UltimateForce>2.6</UltimateForce>
  <UltimateStress>0.12</UltimateStress>
  <Remarks>Pass</Remarks>
</Horizon-Export>
```

My CS:

```
private List<CubeTestDTL> ParseXMLToList()
    {
        List<CubeTestDTL> cubeTestDetailList = new List<CubeTestDTL>();
        if (fuImport.HasFile)
        {
            if (fuImport.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var name = string.Format("{0}.xml", Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", string.Empty));
                var filePath  = string.Format("~/Temp/{0}",name);
                fuImport.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(filePath));
                cubeTestDetailList =
                (
                    from e in XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath(string.Format("~/Temp/{0}",name))).Root.Elements("Horizon-Export")
                    select new CubeTestDTL
                    {
                        Srlno = (int)e.Element("BatchNo."),
                        Accd = Session["ACCD"].ToString(),
                        AvgCompStrength = 0,
                        BreakingLoad = (double)e.Element("UltimateForce"),
                        CompStrength = (double)e.Element("UltimateStress"),
                        CubeArea = (double)e.Element("Area"),
                        CubeDensity = (double)e.Element("Density"),
                        CubeNo = (string)e.Element("SpecimenID"),
                        CubeWeight = (double)e.Element("Weight"),
                        CustDate = (DateTime)e.Element("DateofCasting"),
                        Grade = (string)e.Element("Grade"),
                        Location = (string)e.Element("OperatorName"),
                        MainAccd =Session["MAINACCD"].ToString(),
                        TargetStrength = 0,
                        TestOn = (double)e.Element("TestDate"),

                    }).ToList<CubeTestDTL>();


            }
        }
        return cubeTestDetailList;

    }
```

Problem:

Every time the parsing returns me 0 items. I am unable to debug as the whole linq block passes at once. List Count is always showing =0.

Comment: Why don't you split it up then? Don't use LINQ, just put the same code into a standard `foreach`.

Comment: @Arran any reference code or link for using foreach

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing unbranched XML in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18931480/parsing-unbranched-xml-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried switching

```
.Root.Elements("Horizon-Export")
```

for

```
.Descendants("Horizon-Export")
```

? I do not use linq to query XML though, I prefer going the foreach way, so this would be my first guess.

Comment: It gave me Object Reference exception

Comment: I would also worry about the typecasting you are doing. You are typecasting to Double element UltimateForce, which is null in the first case, that would lead to an exception as well. Also I am unsure what you are trying to accomplish with your code, as you will take only the first element with name you wrote. And add .Value, as you are taking Element value, not the element itself.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal to not get any results from the expression:

```
from e in (LoadXmlStuff()).Root.Elements("Horizon-Export")
```

because in the case of your XML `<Horizon-Export>` *is* the root, not a descendant of the root.

This also means that there cannot be multiple `<Horizon-Export>` tags in the XML, since an XML can only have one root. The only possibility to have more tags would be to wrap them in another tag, which would then become the root.

Comment: `(double) e.Element("Area")` is actually a legal syntax in LINQ to XML, and is safe than `double.Parse(e.Element("Area").Value)` because the first way will return null if the element doesn't exist, the second way will throw an exception if the element doesn't exist.  Even better would be to cast it to string and then use `double.TryParse`.